# Check if Visualforce page uses JavaScript Remoting ? JS proxies were not generated for the controller cannot use public remoted methods in Iframe?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components, managed-package, javascript-remoting

I have several Visualforce pages from managed package (some of them use JavaScript Remoting , some not).
And I need to show one of them (depending on the parameter) on my LWC using iFrame.

The problem that if a Visualforce page uses JavaScript Remoting i can not show it in iFrame.
Is there some way to check in Apex code if a Visualforce page uses JavaScript Remoting??

Maybe someone knows any other way how we can show Visualforce page in LWC ?

I tried the solution from this question but it did NOT help me :
[Similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145577/visualforce-remoting-javascript-proxies-were-not-generated-for-controller-xyz)

Any help will be appreciated .

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Visualforce Remoting: Javascript proxies were not generated for controller xyz: may not use public remoted methods inside an iframe."](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145577/visualforce-remoting-javascript-proxies-were-not-generated-for-controller-xyz) Last answer from Mohith would likely help your situation.

Comment: It did NOT help in my situation.